# Which layout/view/class to use to implement a slider?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-sliding

Here is what I wish to implement..

A *slider like thing*...

> Say My app is a game with 4x4 array of level buttons in each screen
>   and there are totally 3 screens...
>
> The user should be able to swipe his finger from right to left and the
>   slider should "slide" to next 4x4 set of levels...

Just like what the phone functions while we open apps from `homescreen`. 
And if the user `swipes` his finger from *right to left* and there are no levels to the left, the slider should bounce back...

So... What I ask is **which layout/view/class to use to implement such a slider**?

Also, plz inform me how can I implement such a slider which switches between tabs as well (each tab containing different layouts).. I hope I made myself clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand you can use:

- gallery and for each row create your own viw
- ViewPager - [like in android market (slide between view)](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html)

All of this approaches uses adapters and listeners - you can find a lot of examples in internet. I think in your case viewPager is mor useful, because as i understand you want to have many different views.

Comment: Yes.. ViewPager is the thing... 
One more simple question.. How do I add 4x4 grid of buttons to the layout?

Comment: you can use 4x4 GridView ;) =)

Comment: ViewPager and GridView.. got it